# Python3: ftp file upload throws TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, raspberry-pi, ftplib

I'm using python 3.4.2 to upload a logfile to an ftp server (I removed the try and with statements for simplicity's sake):

```
import ftplib

ftp = ftplib.FTP(url)
ftp.login(name, password)
ftp.storlines("STOR " + "mylog.log", open("log/mylog.log"))
ftp.close()
```

The mylog.log file has a "text/plain; charset=us-ascii" encoding. <s>On my macbook everything works fine.</s> When I execute my little program on a raspberry pi (via ssh), I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./ftptest.py", line 7, in <module>
    ftp.storlines("STOR " + "mylog.log", open("log/mylog.log"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ftplib.py", line 537, in storlines
    if buf[-1] in B_CRLF: buf = buf[:-1]
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API
```

I guess it's some encoding and/or local settings issue. What am I doing wrong? What is the best practice here?

Comment: What version of Python are you using on your Mac?

Comment: @smarx I'm using 3.4.2 on OSX as well as on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: That's surprising. I would have expected this code to fail on OS X as well.

Comment: @smarx You are right. I tested this again and it actually fails too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my reading of http://bugs.python.org/issue6822, I think for Python 3.x, you'll need `open("log/mylog.log", "rb")`.

Comment: That works. Thank you! So to transfer a (text/plain; charset=us-ascii) file in "ASCII transfer mode" I'm supposed to open it in "binary mode" instead of "text mode"? I'm a bit confused. I guess I have to take a closer look at the  docs.